# How does SQL Server Agent read SSIS Package Connection?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SSIS packages that have connections that use project params(only database and server), the actual login is set to windows authentication.

So when a SQL Server Agent runs that job step(package) how does it connect with windows authentication? Does it use it's own service account? If so as long as the service account has the same permissions as my windows account it shouldn't have issues right? All the objects in the SSIS packages are tables stored in that same server instance.

If I had external objects that use tables on different servers and such would it encounter issues then?

Comment: By specifying "project params" does that mean you're using 2012/2014 with the project deployment model?

Comment: That is correct. I am using BIDS 2012 and the Server is SQL Server 2012

Comment: Yup, that is with the project deployment model

Comment: Server agent authentication doesn't consider in this case. SSIS will always uses the connection string, whichever there within the config file, which used at the time of deployment of SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

If the job owner is sysadmin and different server are in same domain it should be straight foward.

The secure way is to create a proxy on sql and give the Windows auth credentials. Then configured the package to run as "proxy defined".